# Getting the value an Http Post Method returns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a post method in my web api that returns a string and i am calling the method from a client. How do i get the value that is being returned.

**Post Method**

```
    public String Post(Models.SQNotificationDataAccessRepository.NotificationEntry notificationEntry)
    {
        String externalReferenceID = String.Empty;
        if (notificationEntry == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        externalReferenceID= dbTransactionLayer.PopulateEsiTable(notification);

        return externalReferenceID;
    }
```

**Client**

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:12819/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            Notification notification = new Notification()
            {
                id = 102,
                To = new String[] { "jamesBond@yahoo.com", "cmsds@email.com" },
                Title = "Notification WebService Client Test",
                MessageBody = "The message body will go there",
                DelieveryType = "Email",
                Response = true
            };



            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/NotificationEntry/Post",notification);
            var result = response;

            Console.WriteLine("Successfully delivered:" + result.ToString);
        }
```

Comment: What is wrong with `result.ToString()` what does that output, and what do you want instead?

Comment: its returning a host of things, but what i care about, the externalRefId. I can't find it .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`PostAsJsonAsync` returns an `HttpResponseMessage`, which has a `Content` property that should contain the body of the response.  So you might do something like this:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/NotificationEntry/Post",notification);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Successfully delivered:" + result);
```

Then `result` should contain the value you're looking for.  In the event of something other than a `string` being returned, `result` would have the serialized version of that something.  So it can be parsed/de-serialized/etc. as needed.